# Prove if $T$ is nilpotent, $ST=TS$, and $\dim\operatorname{Nul}T=2$, then $S$ has at most $2$ distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $S,T \in L(V)$ which commute, i.e.
> $ST = TS$. Suppose $T$ is nilpotent with $\dim\operatorname{Nul}T = 2$. Prove that $S$ has at most $2$ distinct eigenvalues.

I tried to directly prove this one, but I failed. Then I tried to prove if $S$ has $3$ different eigenvalues, then I want to show $\dim\operatorname{Nul}T \neq 2$, but I also failed.

I doubt that "at most $2$ distinct eigenvalues" is trying to say that the eigenspace of $S$ is at most $2$.  Even though this is not totally right since if $S$ has $2$ distinct eigenvalues, it can also have $2$ to more dimensional eigenspace, but if there are $3$ distinct eigenvalues for $S$, then the eigenspace of it at least has dimension $3$. Thus probably there is something that restricts the dimension of the eigenspace of operator $S$.

Then since $\dim\operatorname{Nul}T=2$, this implies that if the null space of $T$ continues to enlarge, when $T^{n-1}$ is will be the maximum. I don't know whether this is useful. I also don't know how to use $ST=TS$ this given information.

Any help on this? Thanks

Comment: As a starting point, I recommend considering the case where $T$ is a matrix in Jordan form. Consider what the fact that $ST=TS$ tells you about the structure of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

\begin{align}
x\in\ker{T}&\Rightarrow TSx=STx=0\\
&\Rightarrow Sx\in\ker{T}\ .
\end{align}
Therefore $\ S(\ker{T})\subseteq\ker{T}\ $. Let $\ \lambda\ $ be an eigenvalue of $\ S\ $ with corresponding eigenvector $\ v\ $. Since $\ T^0v=v\ne0\ $, and $\ T\ $ is nilpotent, there's a smallest natural number $\ k\ $ such that $\ T^kv\ne0\ $. Since
$$
ST^kv=T^kSv=\lambda T^kv\ ,
$$
$\ T^kv\ $ is also an eigenvector of $\ S\ $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\ \lambda\ $. But $\ T^kv\in\ker T\ $ by the definition of $\ k\ $. Thus every eigenvalue of $\ S\ $ is also an eigenvalue of $\ S_{/\ker T}\in L(\ker T)\ $.  Can you finish it off from here?

Comment: I think I kind of understand what you mean. If $v$ is the eigenvector for $S$, then by the nilpotent property, there exists a integer $k$ such that $T^kv\neq 0$ but $T^{k+1}v=0$. Then now $T^kv$ is also a eigenvector of $S$ with the same eigenvalue. Thus, if $S$ has 3 distinct eigenvalues, with eigenvectors $u,v,w$. Then by the same idea, there exist minimal integers such that $T^au, T^bv, T^cw$ are linearly independent since they have distinct eigenvalues, and they are in the null space of $T$. This contradicts with the fact that $\dim $ null $T$ = 2. Is this right?

Comment: I think your argument is fine, although it wasn't exactly the one I had in mind.  Since $\ S_{/\ker T}\ $ is a linear mapping of the two-dimensional space $\ \ker T\ $ into itself, it can have at most two distinct eigenvalues, and since every eigenvalue of $\ S\ $ is also an eigenvalue of $\ S_{/\ker T}\ $ then the same is also true of $\ S\ $.